# Story that Hashem kept the ability open to destroy the Bais Hamikdash to avoid destroying the Jews

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, agada-stories-legends

I am looking for a source for this.

Someone told me that there is a story that Hashem asked Dovid hamelech not to build (continue building) the Bais Hamikdash to be able to destroy it instead of the Jewish people if they sinned (if Dovid builds it, it would be impossible to destroy it, as happened with the western wall)

I found sources for only part of the story (see below), but the part I am missing is where Hashem made the request, and that if not Hashem would need to destroy the Jews

---

Bottom paragraph [here.](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20699&pgnum=8)

שיר השירים רבה ב׳:ט׳.
דבר אחר: או לעופר האילים לאורזליהון דאיילתא. הנה זה עומד אחר כתלנו אחר כותל מערבי של בית המקדש. למה? שנשבע לו הקדוש ברוך הוא שאינו חרב לעולם ושער הכהן ושער חולדה לא חרבו לעולם, עד שיחדשם הקדוש ברוך הוא. משגיח מן החלונות זו זכות אבות. מציץ מן החרכים זו זכות אמהות. מה אמר לי? החדש הזה לכם ראש חדשים.‏

שיר השירים רבה א׳:א׳.
דוד בנה את היסודות שנאמר: (דה"א כח) ויקם דוד המלך על רגליו וגו'. ושלמה בנה את העליונות שנאמר: (מלכים א ה‏)‏ בנה בניתי ‏בית זבול לך ‏

Comment: `if Dovid builds it, it whould be impossible to destroy it` God couldn't destroy it? Sounds very theologically problematic.

Comment: @mevaqesh see sources above, it seems to mean that if Hashem will have to choose who to destroy the choice whould be the Jews (not that it would be theoretically impossible)

Comment: I think I heard a similar story but not with Dovid

Comment: @mevaqesh the source that Dovid bilt something before he was told to stop

Comment: Consider clarifying what exactly your respective quotes say, and how they are relevant to the question. Remember, MY is meant to accomedate users who only speak English.

Comment: @mevaqesh does this not do that? "I found sources for only part of the story (see below), but the part I am missing..."

Comment: No it doesnt. It makes some claims, then quotes some text, without clarifying exactly which claims correspond to which text. Consider also using spell check software, as many of your posts contain typos.

Comment: @mevaqesh it was not for the answer, the answer needs to be understood in English, but this is only to help the person who will answer , not everyone

Comment: Questions should also generally be in English. I believe that there is / was an experiment to allow certain questions in Hebrew, but that notwithstanding, both questions and answers must be in English. Non-essential information in Hebrew, could be improved with a translation, but it is, by definition not essential.

Comment: @mevaqesh this is non-essential, the main idea is to find the whole story in one place

Comment: I have heard this said regarding Moshe (as to why he wasn't allowed in to Eretz Yisrael to build the Bais Hamikdash). I believe this was near the beginning of Parshas Vaeschanan.

Comment: @Salmononius2 how can I find the story with Moshe?

Comment: @Salmononius2 I found it or hachaim devorim 1.37 ..."והנכון הוא על פי דבריהם ז''ל (תענית כ''ט.) שאמרו בפסוק (במדבר י''ד א') ויבכו העם בלילה וגו' קבעו בכיה לדורות כי ליל תשעה באב היתה שבו נחרב הבית, ואמרו עוד (סוטה ט'.) שאם היה נכנם משה לארץ והיה בונה בית המקדש לא היה הבית נחרב שאין אומה ולשון נוגעת בו, ואמרו עוד (מדרש תהלים עט) בפסוק מזמור לאסף אלהים באו גוים וגו' וז''ל קינה מבעי ליה אלא על שהשליך חמתו על עצים ואבנים, מעתה אם היה נכנס משה לארץ והיה בונה בית המקדש ולהשליך חמתו עליו לא אפשר כנזכר ויחר אף ה' בשונאי ישראל ויהיה כליונם במקום חורבן הבית,"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yalkut Shim'oni, Shmuel II, 145](https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach.145?lang=bi):

> האתה תבנה לי בית וכתיב לא תבנה בית לשמי כי דמים רבים שפכת כיון ששמע דוד כך נתיירא אמר הרי נפסלתי מלבנוות בית המקדש. א"ר יהודה בר' אלעאי אמר לו הקב"ה דוד אל תירא חייך כי הם לפני כצבי וכאיל ... ד"א חייך הם לפני כקרבנות ... אמר לו ואם כן למה איני בונה אותו, אמר לו הקב"ה שאם אתה בונה אותו הוא קיים ואינו חרב, אמרו לו והרי יפה א"ל הקב"ה גלוי וצפוי לפני שהם עתידים לחטוא ואני מפיג חמתי בו ומחריבו והם נצולין
>
> "Will you build Me a house?" And it writes "You will not build a house for My name for you have spilled much blood".
>
> When David heard this, he was afraid.
>
> He said, "I am disqualified from building the Temple."
>
> Said R. Yehuda, son of R. Ila'i: The Holy One (Blessed be He) said to him, "David, do not be afraid. By your life, they are considered by me as gazelles and deer" ... Alternatively, "By your life, they are considered by me like sacrifices"...
>
> He said to Him, "And if so, why may I not build it?"
>
> The Holy One (Blessed be He) said to him, "Because if you build it, it will last and not be destroyed."
>
> He said to Him, "Is that not good?"
>
> The Holy One (Blessed be He) said to him, "It is revealed and foreseen to Me that they will sin, and I will extinguish my anger against it and destroy it, and they will be saved."